# Thoughts on the use of readonly for any/all instance members of a class?

Tags: c#, .net, coding-style

**Preface**

For some time now I've been using the readonly modifier for nearly all class fields.  I use it for List<T> members, IDisposeable members, ints, strings, etc... everything but value types I intend to change.  I tend to do this even when I would normally like to null a member on Dispose().  IMHO The advantages of not needing the if statements to test for null or disposed conditions greatly outweigh the 'potential' for trouble in objects that 'could' be disposed multiple times.

**The Question**

When do you use readonly, or do you?

Do you or your company have any best-practices and/or coding standards regarding the use of readonly?

I'm curious to hear your thoughts on the following sample class, is the general concept a good practice or not?

```
class FileReaderWriter : IFileReaderWriter, IDisposable
{
    private readonly string _file;
    private readonly Stream _io;

    public FileReaderWriter(string path) 
    {
        _io = File.Open(_file = Check.NotEmpty(path), FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None);
    }
    public void Dispose() { _io.Dispose(); }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Effective C# 1 has an item on this. I highly recommend the Effective C# series.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I use readonly on fields in any situation where the code will successfully compile.

Why?  Simple, if a field reference / value suddenly goes from never changing to changing it can violate subtle assumptions in the class and consumers.  As such I want to be alerted to that change in order to evaluate the implications of this new behavior.

Comment: I agree with your reasoning and usually go a few steps farther by seeking to mark every field readonly and only relax the constraint after careful consideration.  Maybe I take it too far.

Comment: @csharptest.net, that's almost exactly how far I take it.  I'm fairly pedantic on this issue and I'm sure I go overboard occasionally.  But I've seen too many bugs caused from unwanted changes to references so I prefer the route of safey.

Comment: does this mean that you would never or almost never use automatic properties like `public string SomewhatReadOnlyName { get; private set; }`?

Answer (score 5):

Like you, I use `readonly` everywhere I can. Where possible, I use immutable collections too.

`Dispose` is an interesting one, because it's effectively mutating the type from "usable" to "unusable" - I'd be tempted to have a non-readonly `bool` member to indicate that. Then again, I *rarely* find myself needing to implement `IDisposable`. Usually when I use resources, it's only for the course of a single method, so I make the resource local to that method.

Comment: Though I agree Dispose() is a mutation of the object, I see it as akin to the C++ delete operator... essentially the behavior of the object after it's been disposed/deleted is undefined.  Wouldn't you agree?

Comment: @Jon, does this mean that you would never or almost never use automatic properties like `public string SomewhatReadOnlyName { get; private set; }`?

Comment: @DanM: I would only use that form if either I was being lazy, or if I genuinely wanted to be able to mutate it internally.

Answer (score 3):

The `readonly` keyword is just another tool in your .NET toolbox. Therefore use it where it applies! In general you want to great the *least* amount of access to properties,

The reason is that you want to protect your code from being called/accessed from places where you didn't intend it to be accessed from. So going back to your `readonly` question, if you have class member that are only to be modified (set) **once** from the constructor, then `readonly` is the way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Our company does not have any official coding standards about `readonly`, but it's universally agreed on our team to use it whenever possible and where it makes sense (which is often).  It clearly indicates the intention of the programmer or the spec that this wasn't meant to be changed once it's set.

A few of us also use Resharper, which tends to remind you to use it quite a bit.  So your example class would be something that would be considered a "good practice" on our team.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of shorter code, I don't put it in, but **only** if I have a static analysis tool that will guard against misuse.

For example when writing in Java I rely on PMD to make sure I'm not shooting myself in the foot by not declaring all my parameters as final.

You could, correctly, argue that using readonly/final will inform you of your error sooner, but I've been doing it long enough that my spidey sense goes off while writing, and if I happen to miss something the static analysis tool reminds me of it.

Answer (score 0):

Like several other repliers I use `readonly` very frequently. Fortunately [**Resharper**](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) is very keen on spotting when members can be made `readonly`. It shows the reader of the code, that this value is set once the instance is created, which is a valuable detail imo.